Quick way for checking if two objects are deep copies of each other
Assume I have two objects of a certain class and want to make sure that they are deep copies and not just shallow copies.
The code below checks if is can be used to determine if they are deep copies.
import copy

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
          
mylist = [1,2,3,4]        
        
obj1 = MyClass(1,2,mylist)

obj2 = copy.copy(obj1)
print("obj2 is obj1: {}, obj2.c is obj1.c: {}".format(obj2 is obj1, obj2.c is obj1.c))

obj3 = copy.deepcopy(obj1)
print("obj3 is obj1: {}, obj3.c is obj1.c: {}".format(obj3 is obj1, obj3.c is obj1.c))

The output is as expected:
"obj2 is obj1: False, obj2.c is obj1.c: True"
"obj3 is obj1: False, obj3.c is obj1.c: False"

We see that is is only suitable for checking for deep copies if we use it to compare fields of the objects, not just the objects themselves.
My question is if there is an easier way to check for this. I would like to do this check for instances of different classes, i.e. it should work without having to specify what the fields of the objects look like. I would like to end up with a function that looks somewhat like this:
def is_deep_copy(obj1, obj2):
    if "[stuff to determine if they are deep copies]":
        return True
    else:
        return False


You should write your own __eq__ method in your class, since the keyword is reference to that

@Simonalbi __eq__ is for equality, == (which does fall back to identity); there's no magic method for identity, is just says "are these two the exact same object?"

@jonrsharpe yes you are right
